# How to I respond to changed cells in the CodePlex WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my view, I've implemented a the [WPF DataGrid from CodePlex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047):

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="CodePlexDataGrid" 
    Style="{StaticResource ToolkitDataGrid}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"/>
```

It is bound to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
{
    get
    {
        return _customers;
    }

    set
    {
        _customers = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
    }
}
```

When I change data in the grid, it changes, but **I can find no event** that I can handle to catch those changes, e.g. DataGridCellChanged so that I can **save the data** that was entered back into the database.

**What is the process** by which we can capture the changes to the cells and save them back to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the events `CellEditEnding` and `RowEditEnding`, won't they fit your need?

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching it a different way. Instead of binding to events on the DataGrid, implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Customer and handle the property changed events of the Customer objects. In WPF (as opposed to Silverlight) I think you can use BindingList instead of ObservableCollection in order to watch property changes for any item in the collection.

For Silverlight I created a subclass of ObservableCollection that wired up PropertyChanged event handlers for any item added to the collection then bubbled them up to an ItemPropertyChanged event exposed by the collection.

That way I could do:

```
myCollection.ItemPropertyChanged += (sender,e) => {
   // sender is the item whose property changed
   // e is PropertyChangedEventArgs which has the name of the property that changed
}
```